# bobj is not defined in VS 2010

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, crystal-reports

Can anyone know what is this error,when am running my crystal report getting error like  'bobj' is undefined

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'bobj' is undefined

Comment: Have a look at this http://gisprog.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/report/ and also http://forums.asp.net/t/1693771.aspx/1

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and I found this on Google.

Hope it helps!

http://forums.asp.net/t/1512722.aspx/1